# How to set cell above selection in Visual Basic in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set the value of the cell top left from my selection. How can I do this in Visual Basic in Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Selection.Offset(-1, 0).cells(1,1).value = "Test"`

Comment: Thanks! How can I do the same but after the selection?

Comment: Selection.Offset(Selection.rows.count, 0).cells(1,1).value = "xxx"

Comment: Thanks you so much!